# A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server.The specified network name is no longer available

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, sqldataadapter

[image]

```
            cmd.Connection = cnn;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            cmd.CommandText = Psql;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            m_DataSet = new DataSet();

            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(m_DataSet, Ptablename);
            return m_DataSet;
```

> We are calling multiple times fill dataset method, when ever it comes for first time it gives data properly.
>   But from second time its throws "**A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.)**"

Comment: I see that you are reusing cmd variable. I would suggest moving its declaration inside using block. It could be causing the weird behavior that you are seeing.

Comment: Sounds like the connection may already be in use. Close the SQL connection before starting another?